# Download FTP file with URLLIB3

Tags: python-3.x, ftp, urllib3

I'm trying to download a file from a open FTP(I just had to have the link). I have tried to use 'URLLIB3' but got some error

What i tried:

```
import urllib3     

http = urllib3.PoolManager()
r = http.request('GET', 'ftp://ftp2.datasus.gov.br/pub/sistemas/tup/downloads/TabelaUnificada_200802.zip')
r.status
```

And i get this error:

> KeyError: 'ftp'

How to do that?

Comment: GET is an HTTP command, not FTP

Answer (score -1):

As you wanted to download file through FTP(using username and password), you cannot use urllib3 (as it works for HTTP). Instead use ftplib package. [more here](https://gist.github.com/nasrulhazim/cfd5f01e3b261b09d54f721cc1a7c50d)